# Bringing up that something was mentioned before

Tags: united-states, work-environment, etiquette, online-interaction, europe

So this personally is not me, but I saw it happen in our work chat room. A co-worker asked an overseas team to do something (we're in the USA). Their team lead replied about it being a holiday over there and would get to it the next day.

My co worker seemed mad, and brought up that he submitted this ticket last Monday. The thing that rubs me the wrong way is using the phrase "FYI" which to me sounds hostile, or at the least, not empathetic.

Am I wrong to think this, or is there a better phrase to bring up that you previously submitted something and have been waiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always stick to facts ...

> Are you aware this issue was outstanding with no communication to me since Monday - I understand now that you are holiday at your office - is there any chance you can check the status for me now & push this when everyone comes back?  Additionally, can you make sure someone notifies the other offices when they are going to be gone for more than the weekend?

Normally the FYI type situations stem from a poorly formed check on the situation or a lazy communication in layman's terms, though not always.

The situation likely happened because of the first message no having that full explanation -

> Hey `(human)`, On `(day/date+time?)` I opened a ticket `(ticket #)` for `(brief description to ensure right ticket # & issue)`.  I haven't received any updates in my `(email/chat/phone calls)` since `(date of last update)`.  I need the information by this `(date)`, because `(this reason)`.  It would make me feel better if someone could get me status in the next `(hours/days)` so I know where the issue stands.

Had a girl with a photographic memory in my group once.  She was a crazy good worker, did ordering.

- She would work up phrasing.  Then think & rethink the initial email in order to send it, like 5 or 10 minutes.
- After that first send, all communications with her included copy &
  pasted chunks of the conversation she had questions about & guidance
  to what type of answer would make her happy.

  She would still get mad at people & such, but it never bled in to the email world - it was as pristine as her memory.  Everyone had mad respect for her emails...they were basically the gold standard.
- Further when she talked to people (frequently), she would summarize the conversation back, attaching relevant bits so people could confirm or correct any inconsistencies.

I should mention in here - no one likes being reminded of their failures - she was respected for her skills, but kind of viewed as an odd duck - so you can be more forgiving than the purely technical first scenario I presented...

> Are you aware this issue was outstanding with no communication to me since Monday?  Is there any chance you **work with me** by checking the status for me now & push this when everyone comes back?

Comment: I really like this answer, it not only explains the reasoning for why (FYI) comes off as hostile, but also gives a good way to go back and check conversations so that you don't accidentally come off as rude.

Comment: Thanks ether!  Ordering was pretty brutal & she really excelled, so I copied her when I filled in for her.  There can be problems sometimes, but the bosses appreciate it too.  Have I seen you around before?  Do you hang out in the https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails group ever?

Comment: Nope, never in the rails/ruby chats. I spend a lot of time on Stackoverflow and Graphic Designers stack exchange though!

Answer (score 1):

You can always mention something - even something uncomfortable - such that you don't come across as rude.

For example, instead of saying:

> ***FYI***, I sent you this last week!

you can phrase it in a more mild manner:

> I believe the issue was first mentioned last week. I was wondering if there were any updates.

They're still to blame for not doing the work, but there's no need to be rude about it.